# Iphone thread priorities

Tags: iphone, multithreading, sdk, multitasking, nsthread

My application processes audio in its own thread and uses AudioUnits to play the buffers.

When my app enters the background I start to hear quiet a few glitches from my audio.
Now this isn't the worst part.

Before I enter the background I can scroll through my apps UIScrollView with no issues in my audio thread, but after I return from the background any scrolling causes glitches in my audio.

I've checked my thread priorities using `[[NSThread currentThread] threadPriority]` before and after the backgrounding and those don't seem to be any different.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I rebuilt the app under the release setting and everything works and sounds amazing now.

Answer (score 1):

> What might be the issue?

Most likely, your audio processing is compute intensive and there aren't enough CPU cycles left for the system to both remain responsive to the user's input and allow your computation to run full throttle.   The system is attempting to keep the UI responsive and throttling your computation, leading to skips.

The fix is probably going to be to make your computation use less CPU, either by increasing efficiency or doing less work.

Comment: I've fixed that issue in the past.  What is confusing me is that Scrolling, and other UI for that matter, doesn't effect my audio processing until the app goes into then back from the background.

Comment: As soon as your app is in the background, there is -- by definition -- another app running in the foreground, consuming resources, etc...  you are competing for the same set of resources but with more competition.  Without knowing more, hard to say specifically.

Comment: Yea I just don't understand why, when it comes back into the foreground and resetting my thread priorities, my audio engine is acting like it's still in the background?

Comment: Oooh -- didn't understand that part.  Does it remain choppy or does it eventually clear up?

Comment: Even after a while it still has issues when any UI occurs.

Comment: I'm curious what actually happens when an app enters the background and then foreground, (behind the scenes).